# Upload spreadsheet to List Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have an input box with a submit button on my site. I would like the person who uses my site to input a spreadsheet into this - click submit - and the data from the spreadsheet turns into a list. Is this possible? of is there a better way of doing it?

I know you can get lists from spreadsheets by going 'behind the scenes' but I want my user to just go through the main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exposed API for this purpose.

You can use this codeplex feature to do this. Check the license before making any modification to source code:
http://spreadsheet2splist.codeplex.com/